# block shutdown command issued remotely

Tags: remote, shutdown

What started out as initial fun and games between my fellow IT colleagues is now becoming somewhat annoying.  Is there a way to block:

```
shutdown /r /m \\computername
```

from actually shutting my computer down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
shutdown -a
```

Will abort a shutdown in progress. It might be an idea to create a shortcut or batch file which can be easily found when the shutdown starts.

Comment: What if they add -t 00 and -f?

Answer (score 2):

An even better way is to change the admin password on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.bat` file with the following contents.

```
@echo off                   
shutdown -a 

shutdownguard.bat
```

and save it as `shutdownguard.bat`. Then open it and do your thing like nothing is happening. What iT does is spamming shutdown cancel command on the background. You open it and minimize it.

Comment: This is a very bad solution. It will run in endless loops and most probably utilize a CPU core close to 100%. I am not sure if `shutdownguard.bat` does not recursively spawn a new process. In such a case you will soon occupy a lot of system resources. It is much better to use a loop.

Comment: @pabouk can you show how to use a loop?

Comment: @DeerSpotter here is how to loop number of iterations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19138050/320437 and here is how to insert waiting to avoid full utilization of a CPU: https://serverfault.com/a/432323/84914 --- If you encounter a particular problem without finding a solution please create a new question on StackExchange.